# Reference request, self study of cardinals and cardinal arithmetic without AC

Tags: reference-request, cardinals, book-recommendation, axiom-of-choice

I'm looking for references (books/lecture notes) for :

- Cardinality without choice, Scott's trick;
- Cardinal arithmetic without choice.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Jech, **The Axiom of Choice**.
2. Herrlich, **The Axiom of Choice**.
3. Halbeisen, **Combinatorial Set Theory**.
4. Jech, **Set Theory, 3rd Millennium Edition**.

Jech's (first) book is kinda old, and some progress has been made since then, but I don't think there has been a lot that we can say about cardinal arithmetic that was discovered since that book was published (on their order, other structure properties and complexities - sure).

Herrlich's book is not a set theoretical book per se, but it has a reasonable chapter about basic failures of cardinal arithmetics. In particular with the existence of infinite Dedekind-finite sets, which give us a great source of interest for counterexamples.

For the most part, let me tell you what we know about cardinal arithmetic without the axiom of choice:

- The basic addition, multiplication and exponentiation is well-defined as finitary operations. Those are easily found in *any* set theoretical textbook.
- Everything else can fail miserably.

Some interesting papers:

1. Rubin, Jean E. **[Non-constructive properties of cardinal numbers.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02771738)** *Israel J. Math.* **10** (1971), 504–525.
2. Halbeisen, Lorenz; Shelah, Saharon **[Consequences of arithmetic for set theory.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275247)** *J. Symbolic Logic* **59** (1994), no. 1, 30–40.
3. Halbeisen, Lorenz; Shelah, Saharon **[Relations between some cardinals in the absence of the axiom of choice.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2687776)** *Bull. Symbolic Logic* **7** (2001), no. 2, 237–261.

Comment: You should also look at Lorenz Halbeisen's "Combinatorial set theory", and the references within. The book is downloadable from the author's page, [here](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/cst.pdf). In particular, chapter 4 contains several hard to find or new results.

Comment: @Andres: I had a hunch that I'm forgetting something!

Comment: Incidentally, I ran into Rubin's paper just last night.

Comment: I would recommend to begin with Halbeisen's book rather than the Halbeisen-Shelah papers. The exposition in the book is cleaner, and may be easier on a first pass.

Comment: @Andres, I agree. I recommend start with *all* the books before proceeding to the papers.

Comment: Many thanks. I had a quick look to the books and they are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Azriel Lévy's "Basic Set Theory" discusses Scott's trick, and does some discussion of choiceless arithmetic.