# Sets question, without Zorn's lemma

Tags: set-theory

Is there any proof to $|P(A)|=|P(B)| \Longrightarrow |A|=|B|$ that doesn't rely on Zorn's lemma (which means, without using the fact that $|A|\neq|B| \Longrightarrow |A|<|B|$ or $|A|>|B|$ ) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Even **with** Zorn's Lemma, one cannot (under the usual assumption that ZF is consistent) prove that if two power sets have the same cardinality, then the sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Are you sure? What is the most simple (not in length or content, but in the choice of tools) of this question? I mean, it should be true..

Comment: @ORBOTInc. It is consistent with ZFC that $P(\aleph_0) = P(\aleph_1) = \aleph_2$, for instance.

Comment: Under GCH (Generalized Continuum Hypothesis) it is true. I do not know a provably weaker condition that yields what you want, though there probably is one. As to tools, a modification of Cohen's original forcing argument is enough. Not easy!

Comment: I wouldn't dare asking an easy one here ;) I'm not sure what Alpeh1 or Aleph2 is... not familiar with those notations :(

Comment: No, $B$ natural numbers, $A$ even natural numbers. Or are you talking about **finite** sets only?

Comment: @ORBOTInc. No, because that's also not true - take $A=\omega$ and $B=\omega^2$.  Then $A\subset B$ and $|A|=|B|$ so $|P(A)|=|P(B)|$, but for instance the set $\{\omega\}\in P(B), \not\in P(A)$.

Comment: Sorry I messed my argument trying to figure out where to write in math like that :) I meant |A|=|B| (same as the original, just with A in B)

Comment: (Deleted the comment) The question is: is the argument above (the original one) can be proved while assuming A is in B?

Comment: The assumption $A\subseteq B$ makes no difference.

Comment: Hoped it will by making A<=B legit.. :\ Under which assumption we may prove this, if at all?

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment, the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis (GCH) will do it, or anything that implies GCH, like $V=L$.

Comment: Familiar with GCH, not with V=L. How would you construct a formal proof using GCH alone? (And is it actually that hard? Seemed at first glance pretty trivial... guess I should work on my sight ;) )

Comment: Yes, that there is nothing strictly between $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa$ yields the result immediately. AC becomes irrelevant because of Sierpinski's result that GCH implies AC.

Comment: Moving on: Is GCH really the "weakest" condition to prove this?

Comment: I do not know. A first guess would be no.

Comment: Any idea for other things to try?

Comment: @ORBOTInc. What do you mean by 'other things to try'? What are you trying to establish with your proposition?  If you're not familiar with the Aleph notation for cardinals, then I would strongly suggest doing some deeper reading into set theory; you've got a lot of really interesting mathematics ahead of you to learn!

Comment: I actually never saw the notation Aleph_n (but Aleph_0, Aleph, 2^Aleph, etc.) - The truth is, Earlier today I was sitting with my professor at the discrete math course and he discussed with my about putting the question in our upcoming test... Quickly we both understood that its a bit out of the material ;)

Comment: There is the sequence of powers, for which one sometimes uses $\beth_{\kappa}$ (Hebrew letter "beth"). Then there is the sequence of infinite cardinals, for which $\aleph_{\kappa}$ is used.

Comment: Ironically (given the fact I wasn't familiar with the generalized Aleph/Beth notations) I'm Israeli, so I am familiar with the letters :P

Answer (score 8):

One can not prove that $|\mathcal P(A)|=|\mathcal P(B)|$ implies $|A|=|B|$, even assuming Zorn's lemma (or equivalently, the axiom of choice).

It is consistent with choice (i.e., Zorn's lemma) that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$ and, for every ordinal $\alpha$ that is $0$ or limit and, for every natural number $n$, we have $2^{\aleph_{\alpha+n+1}}=\aleph_{\alpha+\omega+1}$. This gives us that for any infinite $\kappa$ there are *infinitely* many different sizes $\lambda$ such that $2^{\kappa^+}=2^\lambda$. For example, this gives us that $\mathcal P(\aleph_0),\mathcal P(\aleph_1),\dots,\mathcal P(\aleph_\omega)$ all have the same size $\aleph_{\omega+1}$, while $\mathcal P(\aleph_{\omega+1}),\mathcal P(\aleph_{\omega+2}),\dots,\mathcal P(\aleph_{\omega+\omega})$ all have the same size $\aleph_{\omega+\omega+1}$, etc.

Similarly, one can also arrange that for any infinite $\kappa$ there is a different $\lambda$ with $2^\kappa=2^\lambda$.

On the other hand, for any positive integer $n$, it is consistent with choice that for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, we have $2^\kappa=\kappa^{+n}$ (the $n$-th successor of $\kappa$). In this case, we have $|\mathcal P(A)|=|\mathcal P(B)|$ implies $|A|=|B|$. The case $n=1$ is the $\mathsf{GCH}$.

(Small technical note: For $n>1$, the result in the paragraph above requires large cardinals. We can avoid this by requiring, for example, that if $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal then $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$, while if it is a successor cardinal, then $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$. This can be achieved by a standard Easton forcing over a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$, and no large cardinals are required.)

Perhaps you are interested in whether there is a condition that does not imply choice but implies your statement or, more directly, whether your statement already implies choice. This is open. It was asked on MO, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204/does-2x2y-rightarrow-xy-imply-the-axiom-of-choice). The statement (that [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622) calls $\mathsf{ICF}$, *injective continuum function*) implies $\mathsf{dBS}$, the *dual Bernstein-Schroder theorem*, in which I've been interested myself. This direct consequence of choice states that for any two sets $A$ and $B$, if there is a surjection from $A$ onto $B$ and a surjection from $B$ onto $A$, then $A$ and $B$ have the same size. It is also open whether $\mathsf{dBS}$ implies choice, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38771/dual-schroeder-bernstein-theorem).

The two links above give about all the results I'm aware of relating $\mathsf{ICF}$ and choice. As Asaf points out in the comments, $\mathsf{ICF}$ has also been called $\mathsf{WPH}$, the *weak power hypothesis*, and was also considered by Tarski. The reference

> Azriel Lévy. *The Fraenkel-Mostowski method for independence proofs in set theory*, in **The Theory of Models**, J. Addison, L. Henkin, and A. Tarski, eds., North Holland, Amsterdam, 1965, pp. 135-157,

indicates that Tarski had already observed that $\mathsf{ICF}$ implies $\mathsf{dBS}$. Lévy's paper also asks whether $\mathsf{dSB}$ implies choice.

(Actually, it appears your question had already been asked on this site. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376509/462) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74477/462).)

Comment: Very intresting. So, is there any way to construct a proof using dBS and choice, without using GCH?

Comment: No, choice implies the other principle, but does not suffice for the injective continuum function principle.

Comment: Actually, in the Banaschweski-Moore paper they apparently quote Tarski as someone asking the question about $\sf ICF$, although they (or maybe he?) called it "Weak Power Hypothesis". Also in a paper by the Rubins about some implications regarding comparability of power sets they also formulate this question (and several others!), most (if not all) are still open to my knowledge.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, of course! We even discussed this a while ago, didn't we? I'll look on my files for the appropriate reference and update.

Comment: The second reference is given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408590/reference-request-self-study/408608#408608).